# Select many values as one column, not a column for each value, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

If you do this query in SQL Server it will give you 15 different columns- one for each postcode.

```
SELECT 
    'CB89RX', 'CB259BL', 'CB19BF', 'CB245HS', 'CB30AP', 'CB12LJ', 
    'CB21RB', 'CB28PX', 'CB28PE', 'CB250HX', 'CB231HN', 'CB58TD', 
    'CB246AY', 'CB42QT', 'CB249JA' AS A
```

What I want is 1 column that contains all 15 values. How can I do this?

Comment: what version of SQL server is it?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want one value per row (15 rows / 1 column) and not concatenated in a single value (1 row / 1 column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to use `From .... VALUES`

```
Select 
    val
From 
  (
  VALUES
    ('CB89RX'), 
    ('CB259BL'), 
    ....
  ) AS T (val)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a02f303cf9f33876cec6400b7ce9d9f4)

Comment: Thanks, I like it the most because then I can apply order by etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `UNPIVOT`

```
select u.postcode
    from tablename
    unpivot
    (
      postcode
      for val in (CB89RX, CB259BL, CB19BF, CB245HS, CB30AP, CB12LJ, CB21RB, CB28PX, CB28PE, CB250HX, CB231HN, CB58TD, CB246AY, CB42QT, CB249JA)
    ) u;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use union :

```
SELECT 'CB89RX' as PostalCode
Union
Select  'CB19BF'  as PostalCode 
Union 
Select 'CB245HS' as PostalCode 
Union 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to avoid repetitive use of **as** .

```
SELECT   'CB89RX'  as A
   union 
   select  'CB259BL' 
   union 
   select 'CB19BF' 
   union 
   select 'CB245HS'
   union 
   select 'CB30AP'
   union 
   select    'CB12LJ'
   union 
   select    'CB21RB'
   union 
   select    'CB28PX'   
   union 
   select    'CB28PE'
   union 
   select    'CB250HX'
   union 
   select 'CB231HN'
   union 
   select 'CB58TD'
   union 
   select 'CB246AY'
   union 
   select 'CB42QT'
   union 
   select 'CB249JA'
```